# Use git pull inside hosting

Tags: git, hosting, pull

I have created a remote repository in my web hosting directory `public_html/.git`

I tried to do a `git pull` from my GitHub repository that has the same content but it failed.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What do I need to do to perform this operation? Is this possible?

I have all SSH setup ready in my Hosting Account.

Comment: I fixed the issue. The SSH setup was relative to my localhost->hosting and localhost->github. I created a SSH key inside the hosting in order to communicated between hosting->github

Comment: BTW it is so nice and fast to pull a versioned repo direct from github to the Hosting dir that I will never use FTP again in my life.